# Tooltips for user suspension/annotation view

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, usability

As you can see, user one has a grey box with a one in it and user two has a red box with a two in it.

[image]
<sub><sup>For some reason they are in different font sizes and alignments as well.</sup></sub>

But...uh...I really have no idea what this means. I assume the red box means "bad" but with no tool tip I don't know what these counts refer to. Could we get a little `title` tool tip explaining "1 somethings" on hover? I assumed the count in Timed Suspension meant how many previous suspensions they have, but a user with a previous suspension still shows with 0 there (identical to one who's been suspended for the first time)

Comment: In "Latest User Annotations" the number is the number of annotations and the background is red if the user is currently suspended. </educated guess>

Comment: @YannisRizos they're both suspended. I was hoping for a tooltip though, since an explanation only helps people that read the Q

Comment: Then it could be a bug, because in the "Latest User Annotations" on ProgSE only the currently suspend ones show with a red background.

Comment: @YannisRizos doesn't match up to only current suspensions on either site I mod