# Please add a policy section to the moderator links page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

We have some elections underway, and it would be nice to have the most important policies a moderator might need listed at the bottom of the /admin/links page.

I'd start with adding a new "Policy" header and add less than a handful of links:

a link to the [moderator eula](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) and perhaps one or two links from the new moderator welcome email

Existing moderators might have some great suggestions of things they use often and had to bookmark for recalling core policy pieces that are handy but used occasionally without needing to search the main meta.

I'm not looking to replace the needed skill of being able to search and use meta and the site blog and other tools, just extending a useful page that already exists.

Comment: Good idea, I have no idea how to find the mod EULA thing aside from the initial email. Also selling users' credit card numbers and/or organs isn't against that policy right? Asking for a friend

Comment: @BenBrocka Tell your friend that organ sales is a legal concept and we don't do legal here - you need a lawyer for that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be pushed out in the next build, > rev 2013.6.28.1143.

Comment: (For anyone wondering what this ended up looking like, the Links page currently has an "Other" section with a link to the Moderator Agreement.)