# Please add a link to the custom close form to the moderator links page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, moderator-tools, custom-close-reasons

I would like the link where moderators can edit close reasons to be part of the moderator links page.

Please add: https://apple.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic

To the page: https://apple.stackexchange.com/admin/links

Perhaps under the **Data Alteration Pages** section

Comment: I completely agree. The current link is such a pain to get to.

Comment: And of course, I am requesting this in general for all sites and not simply for one sub site. :-) (even though most people will only use their one site where they have access to the moderator links page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - this will be pushed out soon.

Comment: Perfect. Would this make sense to push as well or is it more of an obscure case? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167600/please-add-a-policy-section-to-the-moderator-links-page